# How to make an explorer like file manager in Delphi FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

There is no any ShellListView/ShellTreeView component In Delphi FMX.
So, How to make an explorer like file manager in Delphi FMX?
Just simple as to count how many files/folders, certain type files..
and create text , read/write files.
How to deal file system in Delphi FMX?
I can not find System.IOUtils in Delphi FMX.
I think, maybe I totally mis-understand FMX framework.
Any hints?

Thanks!!!

Mitchell Hu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firemonkey is a visual framework. People get so caught up on the way Embarcadero have marketed it that they often don't realize that much of what can be done with VCL can also be done with Firemonkey - it just requires a different approach and perspective.

With VCL, you'd deal with controls that are native to Windows itself. The VCL simply exposes these through the Delphi (and C++) languages.

With Firemonkey, the controls are created with vector shapes and so they're not native to a specific platform. Because of this, it's possible to create any sort of interface and run it on numerous platforms. At the same time as FMX was released, Embarcadero made their units crossplatform which means that *most* of the logic and data units included with Delphi can function on any platform which Firemonkey supports. Some functions are still platform specific but the majority is platform inclusive thanks to clever usage of **IFDEFs**.

With your example, the `System.IOUtils` isn't specific to a framework and it does work with Firemonkey. You do need to add it to your `uses` before you can work with it, but the unit includes everything you'd need to create a file manager. `System.IOUtils.TDirectory` contains routines for creating, renaming, deleting, traversing and manipulating the properties of directories. Many of the old example routines you can find on Google still work (you may want to look for 'recursive directory' examples). `System.IOUtils.TFile` provides a similar set of routines, but for files instead of directories while `System.IOUtils.TPath` provides them for paths instead.

[System.IOUtils on XE3 Docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.IOUtils)

- [System.IOUtils.TDirectory](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory)
- [System.IOUtils.TFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.IOUtils.TFile)

**Expansion 14 April 2013**

Using the `TTreeView` with `TTreeViewItem` children would work to create the directory structure in the visual.

Using `System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories('C:\')` would return a dynamic string array (`TStringDynArray`). Something like this may work (Note: **Tested** - Confirmed that the code example below works);

```
var
  DirArraySize, i : Integer;
  DirArray : TStringDynArray;
  TreeItem : TTreeViewItem;
begin
  DirArray := System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories('C:\');
  DirArraySize := Length(DirArray);
  for i := 0 to DirArraySize-1 do
  begin
    TreeItem := TTreeViewItem.Create(TreeView1);
    TreeItem.text := DirArray[i];
    TreeItem.Parent := TreeView1;
  end;
end;
```

I've now tested the code above and after a small correction (changing `MyArray` to `DirArray` on line 6 as it should have been) and can confirm that it outputs a list of folders/directories in C:\ into a `TTreeView`. Making it recursive wouldn't be too difficult and perhaps I'll expand on that in the near future.

Comment: I don't think there's a cross-platform way to get the icons that the "explorer" in Windows and "finder" in Mac would display that is built into firemonkey. That's where I would get stuck, if I was trying to make an "explorer/finder" like app in Firemonkey.

Comment: That's correct Warren. Personally, I'd probably look into creating a set of icons that aren't platform exclusive. Alternatively, finding those icons and including them as resources might work (and using `TResourceStream` to load them). There are ways to extract icons from executables on Windows (though I can't claim any of the routines I've tried have ever been 'pretty') and I'm sure there would be a way to do the same on OS X. Using IFDEFs would be the solution there but it's probably easier to use platform-generic icons and having your own style.

Comment: Platform integration is actually essential to usability and user experience (UX).  That's where Firemonkey is repeating the same mistakes that Java made over a decade ago with Swing.   A non-native widget appearance is one level of usability flaw, but if the standard file open dialog has one set of folder icons, and your app is not even internally consistent, it's not going to win many fans on Windows OR on the Mac.  If your app uses its own internally consistent set of folder and document icons that don't match the finder (mac) or explorer (windows) icons, you also will confuse users.  Bad.